# Insert data to multiple tables takes too long and eventually the route stops responding

Tags: php, laravel, multiple-tables, laravel-10

I created a customer module from a single form consisting of two tables, the customer table (company) and the person_in_charges table (adding several PIC data for one customer data with a maximum of 5 PIC data).

On the create customer page, there is a form to send data to:
the customer table consists of: user_id, name, NPWP (Tax Identification Number), file_path (company logo), and address.
the person_in_charges table consists of: customer_id, pic_name, pic_email, and pic_phone.

The website works fine when I haven't added customer data with PIC yet. However, when I add customer data and click the 'create customer' button, the page only responds with loading, then displays an error message 'maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded'. However, customer and PIC data have been successfully added when I checked the database. After a while of the error appearing, the website for the 'customer' URL cannot be accessed.

I tried deleting data from the person_in_charges table and only keeping data from the customer table, or I tried deleting customer data and only keeping data from the person_in_charges table, then the 'customer' URL functions normally again.
blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('customers.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
   <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
   <input value="{{ old('name') }}" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" autofocus required>
   @error('name')
    <span class="invalid-feedback text-left" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
   @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
   <label for="npwp" class="form-label">NPWP</label>
   <input value="{{ old('npwp') }}" type="text" class="form-control @error('npwp') is-invalid @enderror" name="npwp" placeholder="Without (-)" required>
   @error('npwp')
    <span class="invalid-feedback text-left" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
   @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
   <label for="image" class="form-label mb-2">Picture</label>
   <input id="image" name="file_path" type="file" class="form-control @error('file_path') is-invalid @enderror" onchange="previewImage()" accept="image/*" required>
   @error('file_path')
    <span class="invalid-feedback text-left" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
   @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-2">
   <img class="img-preview img-fluid col-lg-5" style="display:none;">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
   <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
   <textarea id="address" name="address" class="form-control" data-height="100">{{ old('address') }}</textarea>
   @error('address')
    <span class="text-danger text-left">{{ $message }}</span>
   @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
   <div id="pic-container">
    <div class="pic">
     <label for="pic_name[]" class="form-label">Person In Charge</label>
      <div class="row mb-2">
       <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input value="{{ old('pic_name.0') }}" type="text" class="form-control @error('pic_name.0') is-invalid @enderror" name="pic_name[]" placeholder="PIC Name" required>
        @error('pic_name.0')
         <span class="text-danger text-left">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input value="{{ old('pic_email.0') }}" type="email" class="form-control @error('pic_email.0') is-invalid @enderror" name="pic_email[]" placeholder="PIC Email" required>
        @error('pic_email.0')
         <span class="text-danger text-left">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input value="{{ old('pic_phone.0') }}" type="text" class="form-control @error('pic_phone.0') is-invalid @enderror" name="pic_phone[]" placeholder="62xxxxxxxxx" required>
        @error('pic_phone.0')
         <span class="text-danger text-left">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-1 add-pic"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Customer</button>
</form>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Add new PIC fields
            $('.add-pic').click(function() {
                // Count the number of existing pic elements
                var count = $('.pic').length;

                // Add new pic element only if count is less than 5
                if (count < 5) {
                    var newPic = $('<div>').addClass('pic');
                    var rowDiv = $('<div>').addClass('row mb-4');
                    rowDiv.append($('<div>').addClass('col-lg-3').append($('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'text',
                        name: 'pic_name[]',
                        placeholder: 'PIC Name',
                        value: "{{ old('pic_name[]') }}",
                        class: 'form-control',
                        required: true
                    })).append($('<span>').addClass('text-danger text-left').text("{{ $errors->first('pic_name[]') }}")));
                    rowDiv.append($('<div>').addClass('col-lg-3').append($('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'email',
                        name: 'pic_email[]',
                        placeholder: 'PIC Email address',
                        value: "{{ old('pic_email[]') }}",
                        class: 'form-control',
                        required: true
                    })).append($('<span>').addClass('text-danger text-left').text("{{ $errors->first('pic_email[]') }}")));
                    rowDiv.append($('<div>').addClass('col-lg-3').append($('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'text',
                        name: 'pic_phone[]',
                        placeholder: '62xxxxxxxxx',
                        value: "{{ old('pic_phone[]') }}",
                        class: 'form-control',
                        required: true
                    })).append($('<span>').addClass('text-danger text-left').text("{{ $errors->first('pic_phone[]') }}")));
                    rowDiv.append($('<div>').addClass('col-lg-3').append($('<button>').attr({
                        type: 'button',
                        class: 'btn btn-danger mt-1 remove-pic',
                    }).append($('<i>').addClass('fa-solid fa-minus'))));
                    newPic.append(rowDiv);

                    $('#pic-container').append(newPic);
                } else {
                    alert('You can only add up to 5 Person In Charge.');
                }
            });

            // Remove PIC fields
            $(document).on('click', '.remove-pic', function() {
                $(this).closest('.pic').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'npwp' => 'required|digits_between:15,16|numeric',
            'address' => 'required',
            'file_path' => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg|max:1024',
            'pic_name.*' => 'required',
            'pic_email.*' => 'required|email:rfc,dns',
            'pic_phone.*' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:10,13'
        ]);
        $customerName = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($validated['name']));
        $filename = $customerName . '_' . str_pad(rand(0, 999999), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.' . $request->file('file_path')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $customer = new Customer;
            $customer->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $customer->name = $validated['name'];
            $customer->npwp = $validated['npwp'];
            $customer->address = $validated['address'];
            $customer->file_path = $request->file('file_path')->storeAs('customers-images', $filename, 'public');
            $customer->save();

            $pics = [];
            foreach ($validated['pic_name'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($key < 5) { // maksimal 5 pic
                    $pics[] = new PersonInCharge([
                        'customer_id' => $customer->id,
                        'pic_name' => $validated['pic_name'][$key],
                        'pic_email' => $validated['pic_email'][$key],
                        'pic_phone' => $validated['pic_phone'][$key]
                    ]);
                }
            }
            $customer->personInCharge()->saveMany($pics);
            DB::commit();

            return redirect()->route('customers.index')->with('success', "Customer added successfully!");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Failed to add customer. ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

error
[image]

I have tried previously using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);` and `set_time_limit(300);` but the bug still appears.

Do you have any suggestions or solutions regarding my problem?
Thank you for your response.

Comment: So you code reaches the `DB::comit();` line as you see data in your database. Is your browser redirected by this line? `return redirect()->route('customers.index')->with('success', "Customer added successfully!");` What should the server do to display the data on that page?

Comment: it says 200 queries but you are showing only 6. what are the other 196 and their execution time?

Comment: @Piemol If the data that I input successfully enters the database, the browser should redirect to the index method, and I only call the data that exists in the customer table ```$customers = Customer::latest()->get(); return view('pages.customers.index', compact('customers'));```

Comment: @YourCommonSense For the remaining 196 queries, it is the same as in the picture but done up to 200. I'm sorry, actually, I don't know why there can be 200 queries, and I'm still finding out about this. Maybe because of this, the `maximum execution time of` error appears.

Comment: Step through your code, it may be an infinite loop or recursion. In your screenshot I see duplicate queries (with same conditions).

Comment: @Piemol yeees, I also thought that error appeared because of an infinite loop, but I don't know what and I'm still trying to find out why infinite loop could happen.